# What is a POSIX function according to Microsoft

Tags: c, msdn

I'm reading old C code for dos (1992), in that code, I found a call to `filelength`.

I went to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235394%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to learn about this function:

> This POSIX function is deprecated beginning in Visual C++ 2005. Use the ISO C++ conformant `_filelength` instead.

I try to find more about this function in POSIX documentation, but I found nothing but MSDN reference.

So:

- What does mean "POSIX" in this context?
- Does this function exists out of Microsoft libraries?

Comment: (_Danger:_ Prejudices on display.). It's any function that Microsoft doesn't think it invented that isn't in Standard C — at least to a first approximation.  That's not the only such function; [`setmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235459.aspx) is another.  Another way of looking at it: if it isn't in Standard C and isn't what Microsoft counts as a part of the Windows API, then it is apt to be designated 'POSIX' and renamed with an `_` prefix, even if the function is all of Microsoft's invention. Such names do theoretically interfere with the programmer's name space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - indeed, you've answered the questions asked by the OP

Comment: Names starting with an underscore are 'reserved for the implementation' — it is a bit more nuanced than that, but not by much. Other names are reserved for users (programmers) to use. A name such as `setmode()` therefore collides with the user's namespace. However, with true POSIX functions, you're supposed to request that they are exposed (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` or similar), and they shouldn't be exposed by the headers unless you've defined that. So, those functions are not trespassing on the user's namespace — except Microsoft says they are.

Comment: Of course, the Windows API functions get a clean bill of health from Microsoft, even though they're also trespassing on the user's namespace.  So, practically, it is a defense mechanism by Microsoft to make it harder to port code from Unix to Windows.  At least, that's what it feels like from my side of the fence.

Comment: "What does mean "POSIX" " - What did a simple search for POSIX on google or Wikipedia show you? What was unclear? And why would a C**++** function/method be a replacement for a C function?

Comment: Windows once had multiple sub-systems.  Beyond Win32 it also had Posix and OS/2.  The latter two fell in disuse.  Microsoft's compiler however supported them and its CRT had support for posix functions that are not part of the standard C library, using their native name.  Keeping them around was painful, posix functions have short lower-case names that easily collide with any identifiers that a win32 programmer might want to use.  So they now follow the standard, implementation defined functions provided by the CRT must start with an underscore.  Posix is back in Win10 btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you provide a reference to the standard where it **requires** libraries to use leading underscores? Afaik the standard reserves such names for the implementation, but does no way **require** this. Also POSIX functions are - like the standard library - not part of the runtime, but come as normal library; _possibly_ along with the C standard library.

Comment: @HansPassant *Keeping them around was painful, posix functions have short lower-case names that easily collide with any identifiers that a win32 programmer might want to use.*  That is a horrible excuse for misrepresenting POSIX-standard functions as "deprecated".  What's next?  Calling the C standard identifier `fopen` "deprecated" because a programmer wants to use a short, lower-case name for a function?  What about `string` or `new`?  Are those short, lower-case reserved words excuses for "deprecating" the entire C++ language?

Comment: The Windows POSIX initiative was "just enough to get contracts" and not nearly enough to be functional.  Programming against Windows-POSIX was a joke until I basically gave up in 1999.  https://brianreiter.org/2010/08/24/the-sad-history-of-the-microsoft-posix-subsystem/ clearly indicates that the non-finished POSIX subsystem was shipped with five versions of Windows, despite not having a POSIX compatible shell.  The working versions of POSIX compatibility they acquired from other companies were "broken to ship" and it all fit with Microsoft's lock them to the platform strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, POSIX is the "Portable Operating System Interface" which is a family of standards that initially tried to make all the different UNIX systems compatible.  Thus, you could write against the POSIX APIs, and provided you didn't use non-POSIX APIs, you would likely have a program that would run on a variety of UNIX variants, and later, other POSIX supporting operating systems.

As far as I can tell, `filelength` was a C call that was platform specific.  It was probably a popular call supported by a particular compiler, but may have been a popular call supported by a particular platform or set of platforms.

The POSIX specification dealing with files is "POSIX.1: Core Services" and it seems to have never contained a `filelength` function.  It could be that Microsoft tried to get it added to POSIX and failed, or it could be that Microsoft just mis-documented it was POSIX and fixed their documentation with the removal you mention above.  It may also be an ancient inclusion of POSIX.1, later removed (this is the least likely option).

The current version of POSIX.1 is Issue 7.  It was released in 2008, and is also known as "IEEE Std 1003.1" as the two standards committees decided to align the standards to have fewer standards in the wild.  [You may browse the api bits of POSIX.1 here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html)

To find the file size using POSIX compliant APIs, you use the `stat(char* filename, (struct stat*) s)`, call and then read the `st.st_size` field, or you can use the old-fashioned way of opening it, seeking to the end (`fseek`) and then getting the file pointer offset with `ftell`.

Comment: "In this context" - are you aware of other context or do you mean "programming context" (which this whole site only is about) in general?

Comment: @Olaf Sometimes POSIX is used to mean the committee.  Sometimes it is used to mean "portability".  Sometimes it is used to mean compliance to a particular API, even when the POSIX committee released many different compliance documents, each with many different revisions.  I'm sure someone out there can find other ways of using it, like "POSIX Software", but in this case, file based APIs are fully in POSIX.1, which is the spec covering  "common utilities to support applications portability at the source code level" amongst other things.

Comment: Well, the commitee would be the working group. Re. the revisions: Standard is only one revision, so there is no ambiguity. The only one I see would be the level, but that does also not apply to programming, as it is all the same level as you correctly say. As I see, this is basically all the same field; no "POSIX school of dog training" or so :-)

Comment: @Olaf There are multiple POSIX standards.  There's POSIX.1, POSIX.1b, POSIX.1c, and POSIX.2.  POSIX.1 has been issued seven times.  The new issues add, remove, update, and hopefully clarify the same information, and can be seen as revisions of the standard.  Please don't stand up a straw man (dog training), as it gives the impression that what was said was wrong, by disproving a silly example I never presented.  Of course it's all in the same field (computers), because it's a question about computers.